# Vue.js - Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm using Vue.js and firestore to make a landing page for my project, I've tried to make a registration form to make new account for my website.

I've created a collection in my firebase project, named "users", where the user information where stored when the sign up completed. But when I call the function, the error appeared:

> Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field handle in document users/XcAx6dK1rmZSeoQQO9p3K6kAW3e2)

What can I do? I'll share my code here:

Signup.vue

```
import { Auth, db, usersCollection } from '@/firebase/auth.js'
import * as fb from 'firebase'
import {App} from '@/firebase/app.js'

async addEmail(email,password) {
      var noticeMessage = " Your account has been reserved "
      const {user} = await Auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password )
      await usersCollection.doc(user.uid).set({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      userId: user.uid,
      createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    })
```

auth.js

```
import {App} from './app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';

var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }

export const Auth = App.auth();
export const db = App.firestore();
export const usersCollection = db.collection('users')
```

app.js

```
import Firebase from 'firebase/app'
import credentials from './credentials'


export const App = Firebase.initializeApp(credentials.config);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to eliminate all variables from your call to `set`, and hard code everything.  We need to be able to see exactly what you are passing.  The error message says you a providing an undefined value for a field called "handle".

Comment: thanks to your comment,I've figured the error. My code now works, thanks a lot